# Add new sensitivity fields in Outlook

Tags: outlook, exchange-server

Does anyone know if it is possible to add new sensitivity levels for emails in MS Outlook ? There are 4 default fields: ***Normal, Personal, Private, Confidential***.

[image: Default Outlook sensitivity levels]

I am looking if there's a way to have custom fields (in our local language) e.g.: **Public, Internal, Prohibited** etc... as we're in process of information classification, and this is one of those fine details that you need during the implementation phase.

I've read about Outlook forms, but it seems like this is not the way ahead.

Ideally, if there's a way to have this pushed through a GPO or similar to all corporate account, would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, There are only 4 values. This is not even a Microsoft thing - it is a standard. See, for example, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2076